# ASP.NET Core. NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

Получаю такой исключение при попытки перебрать список. Как его исправить?

```
 NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.AspNetCore.Views_Home_SearchNameMovie.<ExecuteAsync>b__10_0() in SearchNameMovie.cshtml+
            @foreach (var i in Model)`
```

Вот мой метод контроллера

```
public IActionResult SearchNameMovie(string searchString)
    {
        IEnumerable<Movie> MovieQuery = from movie in db.Movie
                         select movie;

        if (searchString != "")
        {
            MovieQuery = MovieQuery.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString));
        }

        return PartialView(MovieQuery);
    }
```

Вот частичное представление

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот Index.cshtml

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("SearchNameMovie");}
```

ps: простите за скрин, дурацкая вставка кода плохо работает(либо моя голова)

При попытке использовать RenderAction пишет:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: чему равно вот это `searchString` в момент выполнения вашей функции?

Comment: Чтобы было проще локализовать ошибку - материализуйте MovieQuery в методе контроллера (`return PartialView(MovieQuery.ToList());`). Иначе к моменту выполнения `db` может уже и не быть.

Comment: searchString я ввожу в input на форме, это подстрока которую я ищу в бд, после нажатия кнопки

Comment: @AlanAugust у вас же локально на машине падает? возьмите отладчик, прицепитесь, и посмотрите, что именно null. Это гораздо проще, чем гадать по скриншотам :)

Answer (score -1):

Нужно использовать [RenderAction](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.renderaction?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2), а не [RenderPartial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.renderpartialextensions.renderpartial?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2), т.к. первый метод будет именно вызывать ваш экшен, который и будет передавать нужные данные в модель, а вот второй просто рендерит вьюху с пустой моделью (там, кстати, у RenderPartial, есть перегрузка, которая явно принимает модель, можно ее использовать).

Comment: Выбрасывает ошибку при попытке использовать RenderAction(добавил скрин внизу вопроса)

Comment: @AlanAugust да вы правы, в core этот метод убрали и заменили на компоненты, как их создавать можно посмотреть тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41353874/equivalent-of-html-renderaction-in-asp-net-core, но проблема в том же, что описана в ответе, чтобы это проверить `@{Html.RenderPartial("SearchNameMovie", new Movie[0]);} ` и будет рендерить пустую вьюху